# How to upcast an Rc<dyn Foo>

Tags: rust, polymorphism, superclass, reference-counting, run-time-polymorphism

Is it possible to upcast an `Rc<dyn Foo>`? If not, why not?

```
use std::rc::Rc;

trait Bar {}
trait Foo: Bar {}

fn upcast(this: Rc<dyn Foo>) -> Rc<dyn Bar> {
    this
}
```

results in

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/core/mod.rs:20:5
   |
19 | fn upcast(this: Rc<dyn Foo>) -> Rc<dyn Bar> {
   |                                 ----------- expected `Rc<(dyn Bar + 'static)>` because of return type
20 |     this
   |     ^^^^ expected trait `Bar`, found trait `Foo`
   |
   = note: expected struct `Rc<(dyn Bar + 'static)>`
              found struct `Rc<(dyn Foo + 'static)>`
```

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48979406/9306292) is a workaround for specific fields.

Comment: I don't follow how this helps. Imagine I want to be able to store the returned reference in a (possibly heterogeneous) vector of Rc<dyn Bar>'s.

Comment: The "duplicate" marked says nothing about `Rc`s. I don't see how it's a duplicate

Comment: Because the issue here isn't the `Rc`, it is the trait objects in general.